# Reduce default spacing between StackPanel child elements

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there some way to reduce default spacing between child elements of a `StackPanel`. For example in the following image, I want them to be more closely placed.[image: StackPanel]

Any help?

Comment: There is no direct way. The spacing is acquired through controls' default padding value. U need to update the margin property. Best is to set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignmnet to Stretch and then apply margin. This way, it will fit in all screensize as you dont habe to recalculate or jardcode margin values

Comment: One more thing you can do is to modify the controls' template and save it in Application resource dictionary (in App.xaml), but beware, this will automatically update the layout of the control through out the application, especially in those cases if you do not provide the x:key property to modified template